# Can't display error document : apache 2

Tags: apache-2.2

My httpd.conf is ..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/dir/

ErrorDocument 403 /my403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /my404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /my500.html

<Directory "/path/to/dir/ ">
AllowOverride None
Options -Indexes
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "\.(JPG|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css)$">
allow from all
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In the deep page of the hierarchy (/path/to/dir/) being displayed default page
What's wrong

access log is

**client denied by server configuration: /path/to/dir/my403.html**

Comment: The way I read the Apache docs for "Order" directive and your configuration nothing is allowed from that directory except the files with the listed extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You've don't have html files in the list of allowed files, so they are denied by default.  This includes your custom error pages, so those don't show up either!

I would create a separate subdirectory for your error pages, and specifically allow html pages to be served from that subdir.